# closed serverfault question

Tags: discussion, migration, close-reasons, serverfault

I am reading [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/193114/linux-e1000e-intel-networking-driver-problems-galore-where-do-i-start) closed question and I find the reason for closing it a bit confusing: Why does it matter the environment where the issue occurs, since it could equally happen both at home for computer enthusiasts and at work in a business environment?

I really don't understand why does it matter *the physical location* where the problem occurs, since it gets the same solution anyway?

How can the question be saved so it can be useful to other facing same problem?

If it really is that important to have separation of home vs work with superuser/serverfault, why wasn't the question migrated instead of being closed?

Comment: Closing does not mean deletion. It mostly means more answers can't be added. Since it was answered well already, not a big deal.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, for the majority of users on SF, this distinction is important for several reasons. Browse through meta.sf to get the picture, this is a regular topic here.

It boils down to "We are not the helpdesk for the internet". Our target audience are professional system administrators exclusively and we have certain expectation of users participating here that make sense in a professional environment but not necessarily so in a home/dev environment.

For the question you linked: This was too old to migrate, so closing was the only option. We also tend to only migrate really good questions to other sites and just close everything else.

Comment: "was too old to migrate" - so it is technically impossible to migrate some questions? and if you migrated it to SU, how would you identify that the question is not within SF audience?

Comment: @CostinGușă the issue happens on resume as the OP stated, which most likely is not done on an actual bare metal server.
Additionally you can only migrate questions the first few days (week or so i think) after it was created.

Comment: @CostinGușă: `how would you identify that the question is not within SF audience?` By reading it and applying our [topic list](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic), how else?